# Why were “although” and “but” used together and “the” before a proper noun in this book?

Tags: conjunctions, proper-nouns

[image]

> **Although** we have not see an UFO **but** there are many people, who claimed to have seen it.

[image]

> The dog thought about **the** Ram and went to him. **The** Ram replied. “another time, my dear friend.

[image]

I am an 8 years old boy. I study in 5. I found two mistakes in my English book: “Although” and “but” were used together, (i.e. as a subordinating conjunction and coordinating conjunction).

and the second “the” used before a proper noun. I argued with my teacher that they are incorrect, but my teacher didn’t admit it, and I was punished for this before my classmates by my teacher.

Comment: You are correct; these pages are full of errors (in addition to the ones that you found). You don't necessarily need to point all of them out to your teacher, but be aware that this book contains mistakes.

Comment: I gave a +1 to MarcInManhattan, but I want you to hear it directly from more of us that your book is poorly written. Sadly, I am not in a position to advise you about dealing with your teacher.

Comment: Thank you, sir, I am going to abandon my school because of my teacher’s behaviour.

Comment: I think the writer of the book may be confused between 'ram' (male adult sheep) and 'Ram' (Indian male proper name).

Comment: You're 8 years old and typing "(i.e. as a subordinating conjunction and coordinating conjunction)"?

Comment: _...a man's experience who have seen a UFO_ is wrong too (and yet one of the authors claims to have an MA in English!).

Comment: I’m closing this question because it's not about learning English itself, now that we've confirmed the source material is garbage